# Group by with similar ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has multiple items with slightly different IDs that I want to group together under one common ID. My table looks like this:

```
ID          | Total
alex_dog       1
ben_dog        2
charlie_dog    3
alex_cat       4
ben_cat        5
charlie_cat    6
```

And I want to be able to group them into one table to look like this:

```
ID  | total
dog    6
cat    15
```

If i leave the _ before the ID that is fine. Is is possible to do a groupby query where you can groupby '_%ID%'?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a bit of string manipulation to get everything after `_` along with a group by on the same value

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ID,CHARINDEX('_',ID)+1,LEN(ID)), SUM(Total) as Total 
FROM Data
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ID,CHARINDEX('_',ID)+1,LEN(ID))
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/BHNY98025